# Creating unique set from array of objects and assigning all object's data to a specific container

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Firestore and here is a problem I'm having.

I created a collection of docs and it's structure is like this:

```
const myArr = [
    {title: 'title 1',name: '10 name',age: 10},
    {title: 'title 2',name: '20 name',age: 20},
    {title: 'title 2',name: '21 name',age: 20},
    {title: 'title 2',name: '22 name',age: 20},
    {title: 'title 3',name: '30 name',age: 30}
]
```

I needed all unique titles so I created a set:

```
const unique = [...new Set(myArr.map(item => item.title))];
```

I added them to my dom so that each unique title would be a heading:

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#main');

for(let i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
    let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
    myDiv.className = 'unique_list';
    wrapper.appendChild(myDiv);
    myDiv.innerHTML = `<h3 data-title="${unique[i]}">${unique[i]}</h3><br><br>`;
}
```

Now I need to add to every "unique_list" div also all objects that are the same as this unique title so that each container would look somewhat like this:

```
<div class="unique_list" data-title="title 2">
    <h3>title 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>name: 20 name</p>
        <p>age: 20</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>name: 21 name</p>
        <p>age: 20</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>name: 22 name</p>
        <p>age: 20</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am stuck with nested for loops and no idea how to achieve this, I would much appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: You probably want to group the initial array by title first

Comment: Not exactly pilchard, biggest problem is with displaying things in DOM as mentioned :/

Comment: You simply group by `.title` and then iterate the resulting object's entries to build the HTML. Here's an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2w64psy/1/).

Comment: Ok, so this solved my issue. 

Gonna further study this piece of code, might actually learn a lot from it :D 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No worries, glad to help.